# I want to clear the input data and then display empty input data

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I was trying to clear the input data and display the empty input data.

this is my input data:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control  input-sm"
                                   required
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   ng-model="q.startDate"
                                   date-range-picker
                                   options="$ctrl.ui.datePicker" />
```

I tired to make null the data, but I don't know how to refresh for displaying empty input data

```
  clear() {
        this.newQuarters.forEach((_value, index) => {
              _value.start = null;
              _value.end = null;
              _value.allocation= false;
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in basic angular js.

```
<input ng-model="q.startDate">
```

in the controller

```
$scope.q.startDate = ""; // will clear the input
```

this should especially work for your case because you have input type="text"
and not input type date.

Comment: my input type is date

Comment: maybe you intended it to be date. but you are clearly telling the browser that the  <input type="text" class="form-control...